# Can JPA entities be serialized to disk?

Tags: java, jpa, serialization, couchbase

I have two machines:

A) Windows XP, JDK 1.7.45
B) Windows Server 2003, JDK 1.7.45

In machine A I can successfully serialize an object to file system and its children and deserialize back.

In machine B, when I deserialize,  the children objects are missing. No exception at any stage is thrown.

If I copy the serialized file from A to B then deserialization in B creates the child objects just fine.

This points to a problem in serialization in B.

The problem does not happen with very simple objects. But, when I use objects annotated with JPA, the problem happens.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="...")
@NamedQuery(name="Category.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Category c")
public class Category implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="...")
private long id;
    @Transient
    private List<Category> subCategories; //These go missing
...
}
```

This problem happens for only certain but not all JPA entity classes.

Any idea what might be causing this? Can JPA entities be serialzed without issues? My eventual goal is to cache JPA entities in Couchbase. This works in A, but fails in B. Even simple disk based serialization has problem in B as described here.

Comment: Please show us the code that you are using to serialize/deserialize your object graph.

Comment: I am using basic ObjectOutputStream.writeObject and ObjectInputStream.readObject. Nothing special. Also, using Couchbase client API which shows the same problem. I converted my code to do JSON serialization as a work around, which is working fine. I have to move on with deployment, can't wait any longer.

Comment: List<Category> is some kind of proxy. If you have lazy-loading, the Categorys are note loaded and will not be serialized. Try (just for debugging) to call toString() of each Category. I beleave, they will be serialized then.

Comment: I think it not a good idea to use the objectserializer at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that prevents you from serializing JPA entities, after all they are POJOs. But what could be happening is that when you try to deserialize it you can't because in the other JVM it doesn't have in the classpath the JPA annotations. Anyway, it should be throwing an exception, so recheck your log.

Comment: The same exact app code works in one machine but not the other. The app is deployed to TomEE 1.5.2 in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the tool for you:

EclipseLink MOXy is an implementation of JAXB (JSR-222) specification. As EclipseLink also provides a JPA implementation many of its extensions are aimed at mapping JPA entities:

@XmlInverseReference for supporting bidirectional relationships (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html)

@XmlPath for mapping embedded IDs (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html).

@XmlJoinNodes (similar to JPA's @JoinColumns) when you need to map by key/foreign key.